# Boolean conditions that span rows in Spark

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to calculate a boolean column based on a group and date range.

I have a table that records transactions with the following row structure:

```
Person GUID - Date - Payment Amount
```

There are multiple rows per person.

What I want is a new boolean column, called `Recent` that is determined by whether the person had a transaction within a time period of say, 3 days prior. It would be True if they have, False if they have not.

Any idea for a query to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on when the start time for the beginning of "prior" is. If it's "now" (the current time), then it's quite easy: you want to find the max date per person and then filter on that being no more than some distance from the current time.

Take a look at [window functions in Spark](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html) and how they can be used with [time series](https://blog.jooq.org/2015/05/12/use-this-neat-window-function-trick-to-calculate-time-differences-in-a-time-series/).

To find the max date you'll use an expression such as

```
max(Date) over (partition by Person) as max_date
```

Hope this helps.